# Finding Average in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote the following code in Python 3.

```
x= int(input ("Enter the first number: "))
y= int(input ("Enter the second number: "))
z= int(input ("Enter the second number: "))
tot = x+y+z
avg = tot/3
print ("average = ",avg)
```

Result when I enter 2,7,1 as the first, second and third number, it prints:

```
average =  3.3333333333333335
```

When I enter 20, 70, 10 it prints:

```
average =  33.333333333333336
```

When I try with 200, 700, 100 it renders:

```
average =  333.3333333333333
```

Please explain me the exact reason to get different values as the average in the above 3 cases.

Comment: All those results are correct. 10 / 3 = 3.333... What are you asking?

Comment: What values are you expecting?